# IE 11 gets unstable

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

After some time, IE goes into this unstable state. The best way to describe it is with this screenshot:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

So after some use, the tabs lose the title of the page, the menubar gets shifted, the X in the upper right will no longer kill the program; I have to use the task manager to kill it. At times the whole browser screen would get black.

I'm also noticing an obvious refresh (they flicker) periodically (every 5mins or so) of all my desktop icons.

I reinstalled the video driver, reset IE settings, and restored advance settings but the issue still persists. Could the video card be the culprit? Are there any other settings I can tweak?  Do you think my windows profile is corrupt?

Comment: Have you tried another user profile?  Its unlikely the video card honestly.  All the same disable hardware acceleration.

Comment: @Ramhound I have NVidia. Doesn't appear that I can disable hardware acceleration

Comment: You certainly can disable hardware acceleration on IE.  Why do you believe it cannot be done?

Comment: @Ramhound, I was trying to do that on the video card.  Read on the internet it might not be an option with NVidia.  But you are right, through IE advanced settings, you can disable hardware acceleration.  I'll report back my findings.

Comment: @Ramhound, disabling hardware accel through IE Internet Options did not fix my issue.

Comment: This does indeed sound like a video card problem, despite you disabling hardware acceleration, the graphics card is still used for other elements ( theme, Aero, ect ).  You can try and disable all those effects to see if that will help though.